# Are the polynomials of form $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +a_3x^3$, with $a_i$ rational, a subspace of $P_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, rational-numbers

I am trying to prove whether a specific form of polynomials form a subspace of $P_3$. I know that any set $W$ forms a subspace of a vector space $V$ if the set $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication (is this right? please clarify).

Based on this, are polynomials of form $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ where $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ are rationals, a subspace of $P_3$ ? I am not sure how any polynomials of this form actually violates the closure properties.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "closed under addition and scalar multiplication" AND nonempty.

Comment: What is "P3"? Is it the space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq 3$?

Comment: Do you really mean $a_2x^2a_3x^3$, as you have written? or do you mean $a_2x^2+a_3x^3$?

Comment: @Hayden Yes. Polynomials of degree <= 3

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have edited the post to reflect a2x^2 + a3x^3

Comment: What are scalars here?  Reals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Are all scalar multiples of $1$  ($= 1+0x+0x^2+0x^3$) in the set
$$
\{ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \mid a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{Q}\}
$$
?

Comment: According to your hint, the answer should be no. All scalar multiples of 1 of the form (1 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3) are not in the set P3. I know this is the right answer but, I would be glad if you expand on the hint and, derive a contradiction (if possible) by assuming that all multiples of 1 are indeed in the set of P3 for polynomials of the given form. Thanks.

Comment: e.g. $\pi \cdot 1 = \pi$

Answer (score 2):

The product of an irrational and a rational is irrational. ..  this appears to present a problem,  and your subset would appear not to be closed under scalar multiplication. ..

Comment: I know from real analysis that product of rational and irrational is irrational. So, correct me if I am wrong, then for a scalar k=sqrt(2), the a(sub i) * k is irrational. Then, it must be true that the scalar multiples of k in this case are not in P3.

Comment: @AbrarHossain  Close.   They are in $P_3$ but not in your proposed subspace. ..